# Using group_by and slice with external parameters

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, slice

I have a data frame similar to

```
df <- data.frame(region=c("north","north","south","north","south","south"),
                 status=c("open","closed","closed","open","open","open"))
```

a variable `samplesize <- 2` (a variable in another df called dataSamples) and another variable `stratifyOn <- "region"`.

I want to group_by what was previously set by a stratifyOn function so that I get a primary set of 2 (the sample size) for each region and a secondary set of 1.

What I tried was

```
primarySamples <- df %>% group_by(stratifyOn) %>% 
                         slice_head(n=dataSamples$samplesize)
```

The first error I got was **Error: Must group by variables found in `.data`. * Column `strstratifyOn` is not found.**

The second error was **Error: `n` must be a single number.** because dataSamples had a samplesize for each region observation.

Is it possible (and if yes, how) to use these external values, or is there an altogether better way?

A stripped-down version of dataSamples is

`dataSamples <- data.frame(region=c("north","south"), samplesize=c(2, 1))`

There are several other variables and observations in the actual df. The value for the sample size depends on which region the user decided to stratifyOn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `.dots` argument to `group_by` to solve your first issue.  Your second issue could be as simple as just subsetting `datasamples$samplesize` but you've not provided a reproducible example of that issue so I'm not sure.

```
df <- data.frame(
  region = c("north", "north", "south", "north", "south", "south"),
  status = c("open", "closed", "closed", "open", "open", "open")
)

stratifyOn <- "region"

datasamples <-data.frame(samplesize = c(2, 1, 10))

df %>% group_by(.dots = stratifyOn) %>% slice_head(n = datasamples$samplesize[1])
# A tibble: 4 x 2
# Groups:   region [2]
  region status
  <chr>  <chr> 
1 north  open  
2 north  closed
3 south  closed
4 south  open
```